# php - how to create a new instance of a class and pass as parameter in WCF

Tags: php, wcf

I am new to php.  I have a web service that I created with wpf.

I am trying to use the following

```
<?php


// Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
$wsdl = "http://www.xxx.net/PURLServ.svc?wsdl";


try {


$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$adminInfo = new $client->AdminInformation();

print 'ok';

// Specify the file to upload
$admininfo->request->authenticationemail = "xx@xx.com"; //required field
$admininfo->request->authenticationpassword = "xxx";            //required field
$admininfo->request->authenticationcustomerid = "12345=";          //required to retrieve customer info.

$wsResult = $webService->GetDataResult;
    print  $wsResult;

// $response = $client->CheckError($adminInfo);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
print $e->getMessage();
}
    echo $result;
?>
```

I get the following error. Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in line 13.

I've tried different ways to try to instanciate the class but none worked.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
$adminInfo = $client->new AdminInformation();
```

(no duh, that's line 13, that's where the error said <-- tongue in cheek, not smarmy).

Ok, for the useful comment:

Right now, you're... well, I don't know what PHP thinks you're doing, but you can't have have `->new AdminInformation();` unless "new" is a property. Event if AdminInformation isn't a class and just a plain function, you'd need a semi-colon there.

You need to either `include` or `require` whatever PHP file has `AdminInformation` in it. If you don't have a file with that class definition, then there is nothing which the service can help with.

As to dynamically loading a class from a Soap call, don't. Have a local definition of that class and then have the Soap call return the name of the class, or better yet, have some factory able to handle the request so that the Soap call won't effect your local class structures.

**Edit**

---

If you want to be able to instantiate a class based on a method call:

```
 // set $klass to either be a reference to the class or a String of its name.
 // String is generally easier.
 $klass = get_class_name(); // or $client->whateverTheMethodIs();
 if( !class_exists( $klass ) )
 {
      //either import the class or handle the fact that the class isn't there.
 }

 $instance = new $klass(/* constructor arguments here */);
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to mention that the original code was $adminInfo = new $client-> AdminInformation();  Whawt I pasted was one of the many attempts to change that.